# Python Summing up Rows in Dataframe with the same Key

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, data-cleaning

I want to sum up rows in a dataframe which have the same row key.

The purpose will be to shrink the data set size down.

For example if the data frame looks like this.

```
Fruit       Count

Apple         10

Pear          20

Apple          5

Banana         7

Banana         12

Pear           8  

Apple          10
```

I want the final dataframe to look like this.

```
Fruit       Count

Apple         25

Pear          28

Banana        19
```

I am using Python's pandas, numpy, matplotlib and other data analysis packages. Is there a way to do this in python using functions in these packages?

Here is the code to create the example dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["Apple", 10], ["Pear", 20], ["Apple", 5], ["Banana", 7], ["Banana", 12], ["Pear", 8], ["Apple", 10]], columns=["Fruit", "Count"])
```

Comment: here is a hint, you will need to use group by operation

Comment: Look into pandas `groupby()` function.  It does precisely this.

Comment: Thank you, all of the posted solutions were very helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `groupby` with `sum()`? e.g `df.groupby(['Fruit'])['Count'].sum()`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["Apple", 10], ["Pear", 20], ["Apple", 5], ["Banana", 7], ["Banana", 12], ["Pear", 8], ["Apple", 10]], columns=["Fruit", "Count"])
df = df.groupby(['Fruit'])['Count'].sum()
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
Fruit
Apple     25
Banana    19
Pear      28
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `groupby` with `as_index=False`, and `sum`:

```
>>> df.groupby('Fruit',as_index=False)['Count'].sum()
    Fruit  Count
0   Apple     25
1  Banana     19
2    Pear     28
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes! its as easy as

`df.groupby("Fruit").sum()`

Answer (score 2):

This should be the shortest way to get what you are after:

```
df.groupby("Fruit").sum()
```

Outputs:

```
Fruit      Count       
Apple      25
Banana     19
Pear       28
```

Answer (score 1):

use `groupby` with `sum`

```
df = df.groupby('Fruit').sum()
print(df)
```

Outputs

```
Fruit      Count     
Apple      25
Banana     19
Pear       28
```